# Creating a matrix of 0 and 1 that maintains its shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am attempting to create a matrix of 1 if every 2nd  column value is greater than the previous column value and 0s if less, when I use np.where it just flattens it I want to keep the first column and the last column and it shape.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

newd=pd.DataFrame()
for x in df.columns[1::2]:
        if bool(df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc(x)] <= 
df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc(x)-1]):
            newdf.append(1)
        else:newdf.append(0)
```

Comment: maybe something like this     newdf=[]
#combinations for Fundamentals
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

for x in df.columns[1::2]:
    if any(df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc(x)] <= df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc(x)-1]):
            newdf.append(0)
    else:newdf.append(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was a little vague, but I will answer a question that I think gets at the heart of what you are asking:

Say you start with a matrix:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Which creates:

```
          A         B         C         D
0  2.464130  0.796172 -1.406528  0.332499
1 -0.370764 -0.185119 -0.514149  0.158218
2 -2.164707  0.888354  0.214550  1.334445
3  2.019189  0.910855  0.582508 -0.861778
4  1.574337 -1.063037  0.771726 -0.196721
5  1.091648  0.407703  0.406509 -1.052855
6 -1.587963 -1.730850  0.168353 -0.899848
7  0.225723  0.042629  2.152307 -1.086585
```

Now you can use `pd.df.shift()` to shift the entire matrix, and then check the resulting columns item by item in one step. For example:

```
df1.shift(1)
```

Creates:

```
          A         B         C         D
0 -0.370764 -0.185119 -0.514149  0.158218
1 -2.164707  0.888354  0.214550  1.334445
2  2.019189  0.910855  0.582508 -0.861778
3  1.574337 -1.063037  0.771726 -0.196721
4  1.091648  0.407703  0.406509 -1.052855
5 -1.587963 -1.730850  0.168353 -0.899848
6  0.225723  0.042629  2.152307 -1.086585
7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

And now you can check the resulting columns with a new matrix as so:

```
df2 = df1.shift(-1) > df1
```

which returns:

```
       A      B      C      D
0  False  False   True  False
1  False   True   True   True
2   True   True   True  False
3  False  False   True   True
4  False   True  False  False
5  False  False  False   True
6   True   True   True  False
7  False  False  False  False
```

To complete your question, we convert the True/False to 1/0 as such:

```
df2 = df2.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
```

Which returns:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0  0  1  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  0
3  0  0  1  1
4  0  1  0  0
5  0  0  0  1
6  1  1  1  0
7  0  0  0  0
```

In one line:

```
df2 = (df1.shift(-1)>df1).replace({True:1,False:0})
```

Comment: thank you but how do I do this for every second column since only the results of B and D matter

Comment: nvm I found a way by transposing 
t=np.transpose(df2)

s = t.iloc[1::2]